# Using SQL to Aggregate and Calculate Stats

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have shoot 'em game where users compete against each other over the course of a week to accumulate the most points. I want to write a query that aggregates statistical data from the shots table. The tables and relationships of concern here are:

- user has many competition_periods
- competition_period belongs to user
- competition_period has many shots
- shot belongs to competition_period

In the shots table I have the following fields to work with:

- result --> string values: WON, LOST or TIED
- amount_won --> integer values: e.g., -100, 0, 2000, etc.

For each user, I want to return a result set with the following aggregated stats:

- won_count
- lost_count
- tied_count
- total_shots_count (won_count + lost_count + tied_count)
- total_amount_won (sum of amount_won)
- avg_amount_won_per_shot (total_amount_won / total_shots_count)

I've worked on this query for few hours now, but haven't made much headway. The statistical functions trip me up. A friend suggested that I try to return the results in a new virtual table called shot_records.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have virtual tables, they are called views instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the basic solution, computing the statistics across all shots for a given player (you didn't specify if you want them on a per-competition-period basis or not):

```
 SELECT user, SUM(IF(result = 'WON', 1, 0))  AS won_count, 
              SUM(IF(result = 'LOST', 1, 0)) AS lost_count, 
              SUM(IF(result = 'TIED', 1, 0)) AS tied_count, 
              COUNT(*)                       AS total_shots_count, 
              SUM(amount_won)                AS total_amount_won, 
              (SUM(amount_won) / COUNT(*))   AS avg_amount_won_per_shot 
 FROM user U INNER JOIN competition_periods C ON U.user_id = C.user_id
 INNER JOIN shots S ON C.competition_period_id = S.competition_period_id
 GROUP BY user
```

Note that this includes negatives in calculating the "total won" figure (that is, the total is decreased by losses).  If that's not the correct algorithm for your game, you would change `SUM(Amount)` to `SUM(IF(Amount > 0, Amount, 0))` in both places it occurs in the query.

Comment: Man, how the heck did you come up with that so quickly?

Comment: Yes, in the amount_won the values can be positive or negative, so just summing that will give you the total amount won (or lost).

Comment: Honestly, it's a pretty straightforward query.  The tricky bit is handling the "Count this row but only if some condition is true" that you need for the first three columns, and since that actually comes up fairly frequently I just had to look up the MySQL syntax for IF (other DBs would have to use the much-more-verbose CASE).

Comment: Also, credit is due to the extremely clear statement of the problem in the original question.